# How do I get cookies to to be sent with my requests to the backend in ember app?

Tags: cookies, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, httpcookie

Is there a way in Ember to send cookies with the requests to the backend?

For example: if my client URL is `protocol://example.com`. The cookies that belong to the same domain will be in the request header when I navigate to `protocol://example.com/profile`. However, they do not persist in the subsequent request/s the profile route model method makes -> example to `protocol://example-host/posts`. How do I make those cookies persist?

`/app/routes/profile.js`:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from "simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll("post");
  },

  renderTemplate() {
    this.render("header", {
      outlet: "header"
    });

    this.render("profile");
  }
});
```

`/app/adapters/application`:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://example-host.com',
  corsWithCredentials: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
});
```

Comment: Does your backend explicitly set the `Path` attribute of the cookie? If not, it should set it to `/` - which encompasses both `/profile` and `/posts`. Otherwise, a cookie set on `/profile` will NOT be sent to `/posts` as it does not fall "under" that route.

Comment: No the backend doesn't set the path attribute.

Answer (score 9):

This works in my production app. Code in `app/adapters/application.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

$.ajaxSetup({
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajax(url, method, hash) {
    hash = hash || {};
    hash.crossDomain = true;
    hash.xhrFields = {
      withCredentials: true
    };
    return this._super(url, method, hash);
  }
})
```

Comment: What about in development?

Comment: It works in both for me. I was just saying it's solid.

Comment: Just curios what is the below code doing?
$.ajaxSetup({
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});

Comment: It ensures you send HTTP-cookie with AJAX requests to server and your session etc. is working.

Comment: Are your server and client in the same domain?

Comment: Yep, but it was different port that made the difference I think.

Comment: Thanks, mine is working too in the same domain but different ports. Had to set the "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true for all my responses coming from server.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set individual header values to be sent with each ember-data request. Useful if you need to pass an API key with all your requests.

In your adapter (`app/adapters/application.js`):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { get } from '@ember/object';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: computed(function() {
    return {
      'API_KEY': get(document.cookie.match(/apiKey\=([^;]*)/), '1'),
      'ANOTHER_HEADER': 'Some header value'
    };
  }).volatile()
});
```