# Ember simple auth and cookie headers

Tags: authentication, cookies, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am currently working on an Ember 2.4.x application and I am using `ember-simple-auth` with a custom Authenticator and a custom Authoriser.

Upon successful authentication, the server responds with a json body containing information about the current user plus a cookie in the Response Headers:

```
Response Headers:
  Set-Cookie:Authorization=1s39gpzqy4d0w1quxekavz6yj1;Path=/
```

Now, the only thing I need, for each consecutive requests, is to send back that same cookie.
I understand that with `ember-simple-auth`, I can use the `block` callback in order to set an additional header in my the custom authoriser. However, I could not find a way to resend that exact same cookie with each requests.

Also I am wondering whether I need an Authoriser at all since I am not setting any header, the server only cares about that cookie.

Answer (score 1):

If your authentication server issues a cookie you don't really need an authorizer at all as the browsers will automatically send the cookie with each consecutive request.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I got rid of the authorizer for now even though i am planning to pull some code from the authorizer mixin so that the application will route automatically in case the server sends a 401. Unfortunately I am still out ofluck with this cookie thing. It seems that either the browser or Ember are not sending back the cookie to the server. Is there anything I should be doing at all?

Comment: @marcoow this mean we don't need to do anything in ember-simple-auth. But how will ember-simple-auth will check if user is actually signed in or not etc?

Comment: The idea would be that you implement a custom authenticator that just *assumes* the cookie to be present and the user to be successfully logged in when the login request succeeds (responds with a 200) although it cannot actually see the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to getting this to work. Basically I first followed the answer of [that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851840/how-do-i-get-cookies-to-to-be-sent-with-my-requests-to-the-backend-in-ember-app)

Then, in my custom authenticator I am re-using the `makeRequest` method on which I had to set the `xhrFields` property:

```
makeRequest(data, options) {
  let serverTokenEndpoint = get(this, 'serverTokenEndpoint');
  let requestOptions = $.extend({
    url:      serverTokenEndpoint,
    type:     'POST',
    // The contentType must be passed to Jetty as it will default to
    // 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    data,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },

    beforeSend(xhr, settings) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', settings.accepts.json);
    }
  }, options || {});

  return $.ajax(requestOptions);
}
```

I also found out that the server had to set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` in the `Response Headers` otherwise Ember would through an error.